# rvest scraper working, but not returning newest data from website + not returning links

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, missing-data

I'm using rvest to scrape the title, date and nested link for Danish parliamentary committee agendas. In general it works fine and I get the data I want, but I have two issues that I hope you can help with. As an example I'm scraping this committee website for the information in the table and the nested links. https://www.ft.dk/da/udvalg/udvalgene/liu/dokumenter/udvalgsdagsordner?committeeAbbreviation=LIU&session=20211

**First problem - Missing newest data:**
The scraper does not get the newest data although it is available on the website. For example on the particular page in the link there are two entries from June that is not "detected". This problem is consistent with the other committee pages, where it also does not pick up the newest data entries.

Q: Does anybody know why the data is not showing up in R even though it is present on the website and have a solution for getting the data?

**Second problem - Missing links:**
For the particular committee (LIU) linked to above, I'm not able to get the full nested links to the agendas, even though it works for all the other committees. Instead it just returns [www.ft.dk](http://www.ft.dk) as the nested link. Up until now I have solved it by manually adding every nested link to the dataset, but it is rather time consuming. Does anybody know why this is not working and can help solve it?

Q: How do I get the nested link for the individual committee agenda?

I'm using loops to go through all the different committee pages, but here's the basic code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(httr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

# base url of Folketinget for committee agendas
base.url <- "https://www.ft.dk/da/udvalg/udvalgene/"

#List of all committees
committee <- c("§71","BEU", "BUU", "UPN", "EPI", "ERU", "EUU", "FIU", "FOU", "FÆU", "GRA", "GRU", "BOU", "IFU", "KIU", "KEF", "KUU", "LIU", "MOF", "REU", "SAU", "SOU", "SUU", "TRU", "UFU", "URU", "UUI", "UFO", "ULØ", "UFS", "UPV", "UER", "UET", "UUF")


## Set up search archives
if (!dir.exists("./DO2011-2022/")) {
  dir.create("./DO2011-2022/")
} 
search.archive <- "./DO2011-2022/dagsorden_search/"
if (!dir.exists(search.archive)) {
  dir.create(search.archive)
}


# empty data set
cols <- c("date", "title", "cmte", "link")
df <- cols %>% t %>% as_tibble(.name_repair = "unique") %>% `[`(0, ) %>% rename_all(~cols)

## Set up main date parameters
first.yr <- 2011
last.yr <- 2022
session <- 1:2

# main loop over committees
for (i in committee) {
  
  for(current.yr in first.yr:last.yr) {
    
      for(j in session) {
        print(paste("Working on committee:", i, "Year", current.yr, "session", j))
        
        
        
        result.page <- 1
  
        
  
        ## INTERIOR LOOP OVER SEARCH PAGES
              repeat {
              
                # build archive file name
                file.name <- paste0(search.archive, i,
                        current.yr, "session", j,
                        "-page-",
                        result.page,
                        ".html")
                
                
                # construct url to pull 
                final.url <- paste0(base.url,i, "/dokumenter/udvalgsdagsordner?committeeAbbreviation=", i,
                                    "&session=", current.yr, j, "&pageSize=200&pageNumber=", result.page)
    
                # check archive / pull in page
                
                #Fix problem with missing data from 2021 page - its because newly downloaded data is not on previous downloaded pages.
                if(!current.yr == 2021){
                
                      if (file.exists(file.name)) {
                      page <- read_html(x = file.name)
                      } else {
                      page <- read_html(final.url)
                      tmp <- page %>% as.character
                      #Sys.sleep(3 + rpois(lambda = 2, n = 1))
                      write(x = tmp, file = file.name)
                      }
                }
                else{
                   page <- read_html(final.url)
                      tmp <- page %>% as.character
                      Sys.sleep(5)
                      write(x = tmp, file = file.name)
                }
    
                           # only grab length of results once
                          if (result.page == 1) {
                          # get total # search results
                          total.results <- page %>% 
                          html_nodes('.pagination-text-container-top .results') %>% 
                          html_text(trim = T) %>% 
                          str_extract("[[:digit:]]*") %>% 
                          as.numeric
      
                    # break out of loop if no results on page (typical for session=2)
                    if (length(total.results) == 0) break
      
      
                    # count search pages to visit (NB: 200 = number of results per page)
                    count.pages <- ceiling(total.results / 200)
      
                    # print total results to console
                     print(paste("Total of", total.results, "for committee", i))
                          }
                
                
             

    if(i == "FOU"|i == "GRU"){
      titles <- page %>% html_nodes('.column-documents:nth-child(1) .column-documents__icon-text') %>%  html_text(trim = T) 
    }
    else{
    titles <- page %>% html_nodes('.highlighted+ .column-documents .column-documents__icon-text') %>%  html_text(trim = T) }

    dates <- page %>% html_nodes('.highlighted .column-documents__icon-text') %>%  html_text(trim = T) 
    
     # Solution to problem with links for LIU
     if(i == "LIU"){
       links <- page %>% html_nodes(".column-documents__link") %>% html_attr('href') %>% unique()
     }
    
    else{
    links <- page %>% html_nodes(xpath = "//td[@data-title = 'Titel']/a[@class = 'column-documents__link']") %>% html_attr('href')
    }
    
    links <- paste0("https://www.ft.dk", links)
    
    
    
    
  
    
  
     # build data frame from data
      df <- df %>% add_row(
      date = dates,
      title = titles,
      cmte = i,
      link = links)
      
    
                ## BREAK LOOP when result.page == length of search result pages by year
                if (result.page == count.pages) break
    
                ## iterate search page by ONE
                result.page <- result.page + 1
                
              } #END PAGE LOOP
        
     
         
        
        
      } #END SESSION LOOP
    
  } #END YEAR LOOP
  
} #END COMMITTEE LOOP
    

end <- Sys.time()

#Scraping time
end - start
```

If I alternatively use selectorgadget instead of xpath to get the links, I get the following error:
Error in tokenize(css) : Unclosed string at 42

```
links <- page %>% html_nodes(".highlighted .column-documents__icon-text']") %>% html_attr('href')
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not experience the problem with the missing dates. For the links I used the following code and it worked, as far as I could tell: `links <- page %>% html_nodes(".column-documents__link") %>% html_attr('href') %>% unique()`.
However, I am not fully understanding, how you loop and what exactly you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Datapumpernickel - Your solution to the links problem worked. I have edited the code with the full code I'm using. Also, since you didn't have the problem with the missing data, I figured out the problem myself - It's because I have previously downloaded and archived the newest page and use that so I don't have to redownload the pages. And because I was using the old page the newest data was of course not present. Silly mistake. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Great to hear. Thanks for adding the code, I do not have time to look at it right now, but your problem is solved anyways, right?

Comment: Yes, the problem is solved, so no need for more help, thanks!